# Параметры в конструктор Spring

Tags: java, spring, xml

Можно ли в XML коде добавить два бина в конструктор?

Два класса имплементируют один и тот же интерфейс, но нужно, чтобы в конструкторе каждый занял свое место.

Какие именно ключевые слова мы используем в XML?

```
<constructor-arg ref= бин класса />
```

Именно через XML. Не знаю, в чем проблема, но аннотации почему-то не поддерживаются.

Comment: Приведите пример вашей конфигурации / кода.  Сейчас тяжело понять, в чём проблема.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Comment: Nowhere Man, я нашел решение.
Через сетеры, которые изменяются как
 <property name="mus1" ref="первый класс"/>
 <property name="mus2" ref="второй класс"/>
Конструктор оставил пустым. и когда создаётся экземляр класса, параметры уже заданы. Спасибо